# Erro ao efetuar login em site que fiz usando php

Tags: php

Boa tarde,

Criei um site em que o mesmo tem area de login, no entanto ao efetuar login nao estou a conseguir aceder, sendo que aparece este erro:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/disk10/2410210/www/bijuartes.myartsonline.com/login.php:1) in /srv/disk10/2410210/www/bijuartes.myartsonline.com/login.php on line 44

Alguem me pode ajudar, sff?

Este é o código da pagina login.php:

```
<?php @session_start();?>
<html>
<head>
<title>BijuArtes - Login</title>
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <style>
            body{background-color: #d6a619; margin:0px; background-image: url("img/principais/lr.jpg");
            background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: fixed;}  
            label{display: inline-block; width: 100px;}
        </style> 
</head>
<body>

<!-----------------------------PHP-------------------->
<?php 
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['username']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['password']);

    if($user == "" || $pass == "") {
        echo "Os seus dados estão incorrectos. Tente novamente.";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<a href='login.php'>Voltar</a>";
    } else {
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$user' AND password=md5('$pass')")
                    or die("Não foi possível neste momento executar o seu pedido.");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if(is_array($row) && !empty($row)) {
            $validuser = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['validado'] = $validuser;
            $_SESSION['nome'] = $row['nome'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['adm'];
            echo $_SESSION['id'];
        } else {
            echo "<p style=\"text-align: left; color: #d6a619; font-family: Pristina; font-size:30px; margin-top:100px; margin-left: 100px;\">Username ou Palavra Pass errados";
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "<a href='login.php'>Voltar</a>";
        }

        if(isset($_SESSION['validado'])) {
            header('Location: indexUser.php');          
        }
    }
} else {
?>

<!-----------------------------HTML-------------------->
<header class="banner">
            <img src="img/principais/logo.png" alt="" style="float:left; height: 250px; width: 250px">
            <h1 style="font-family:'Pristina'; font-size:40px;  color:#d6a619">
                Bijuterias e Artesanato</h1> 
                <nav class="navegacao">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </nav> 
</header>       
<h2 style="text-align: left; color: #d6a619; font-family: Pristina; font-size:50px; margin-left:200px;">Login</h2> 
    <form class="form" name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <div class="login">
            <label>Username</label>
             <input  type="text" name="username" required pattern="[a-zA-z]{3,}" style="color: black">
        </div>
        <div class="login">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input  id="password" name="password" type="password"  title="Por Favor introduza uma palavra pass válida" required style="color: black">
        </div>

        <div class="login">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" style="color: goldenrod; background-color: black; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;" value="Login">
            <input type="reset" name="reset" style="color: black; background-color: #ffd966; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;" value="Limpar">   
        </div>

    </form>
    <br/>
    <p style="text-align: center; color:  #e6ac00; font-size: 15px; font-family: Verdana">Área reservada a utilizadores registados. Caso queira registar-se <a href="registo.php">Clique aqui</p>

<?php
}
?>
```

E este é o código da pagina indexUser.php (esta página serve para quando se efetua login aceder á area do utilizador/admin):

```
<?php @session_start(); ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>BijuArtes - Área Utilizador</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
       <style>
            body{background-color: #d6a619; margin:0px; background-image: url("img/principais/fundo.jpg");
            background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: fixed;}  
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    if(isset ($_SESSION['nome'])) {         
    ?>

    <?php   
    } else {
        echo "Faça login  para ver esta página.<br/><br/>";
        echo "<a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
    }
    ?>
        <header class="banner">
            <img src="img/principais/logo.png" alt="" style="float:left; height: 250px; width: 250px">
            <h1 style="font-family:'Pristina'; font-size:40px;  color:#d6a619">
                Bijuterias e Artesanato <br/>       


            <audio autoplay controls style='float: right'> 
                <source src="audio/som.mp4" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>

            <nav class="navegacao">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="bijuterias.html">Bijuterias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="artesanato.html">Artesanato</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="contactos.php">Contactos</a></li> 
                    <li style="float: right"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                    <li style="float: right" ><a href="dados.php">Ver meus dados</a></li>
                    <li><br/></li>
                    <?php
                    if($_SESSION['admin'] == 1) {
                    echo '<li><a href="vertodas.php">Caixa de mensagens</a></li>
                    <li><a href="vernovas.php">Novas mensagens</a></li>
                    <li style="float: right"><a href="produtos.php">Consultar/Adicionar Produtos</a></li>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>   
                <br/>
                <h1 style="font-family: Pristina; font-size: 40px; text-align: left; color: goldenrod; ">Olá  <?php echo $_SESSION['nome']?> </h1>  
            </nav>

        </header>

            <section class="moldura">
                <div class="artigo">
                    <img src="img/principais/bijuterias.jpg" alt="" style="border-radius: 10%; width: 80%; height:80%; margin: 40px;"/>    
                </div>
                <div class="artigo">
                    <img src="img/principais/artesanato.jpg" alt="" style="border-radius: 10%; width: 80%; height:80%; margin: 40px;"/>    
                </div>

                 <div class="artigo">
                    <img src="img/principais/reciclar.jpg" alt="" style="border-radius: 10%; width: 80%; height:80%; margin: 40px;"/>    
                </div>
                 <div class="artigo">
                    <img src="img/principais/bijux.jpg" alt="" style="border-radius: 10%; width: 80%; height:80%; margin: 40px;"/>    
                </div>  
             </section>


    </body>
</html>
```